# How to append keys to values for {Key,Value} pair RDD and How to convert it to an rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Suppose i am having 2 files in file1,file2 in dataset directory:

`val file = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///root/data/dataset").map((x,y) => y + "," + x)`

in the Above code i am trying to get an rdd having values:-> value,key as single value into rdd

suppose filename is file1 and say 2 records:

```
file1:

1,30,ssr

2,43,svr
```

And

```
file2:

1,30,psr

2,43,pvr
```

The desired rdd output is:

```
(1,30,ssr,file1),(2,43,svr,file1),(1,30,psr,file2),(2,43,pvr,file2)
```

Can we achieve this?
if possible Please Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var files = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///root/data/dataset")

var yourNeededRdd = files
  .flatMap({
    case (filePath, fileContent) => {
      val fileName = filePath.split('/).last
      fileContent.split("\n").map(line => line + "," + fileName)
    }
  })
```

Comment: thanks @Sarvesh Kumar Singh.it is working but i am getting : ,filename is added at the start of records

Comment: thanks @Sarvesh Kumar Singh.. its working one thing i just swapped fileName and line in map function...that is giving correct result

Comment: just to state the obvious (just as a warning for other people reading this answer) - for this solution, any file in the folder can't be more than local RAM size. That's what "whole" basically suggests.